# Do I need a visa to enter Georgia?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, palestine-citizens

I have a Palestinian Authority passport and a work permit and residence in Turkey. I also have USA and Schengen multiple visas. I have used the Schengen visa several times and it's valid until April 2019. The USA visa is valid until June 2019.

Do I need a visa to enter Georgia?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need a visa.

You can enter for  90 calendar days in any 180-day period on either your Schengen or USA visa.

[Information here](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=206&lang=Eng)

> 1. Aliens holding a visa and/or a residence permit of any country listed above may enter and stay in Georgia without visa for 90
>      calendar days in any 180-day period.
> 2. For the purpose of entering and staying in Georgia without visa, a visa and/or a residence permit of a respective country shall be valid
>      on the day of entry into Georgia (crossing the border), which must be
>      evidenced by a travel and/or other appropriate document.